# Jackson readTree() ignore null and empty values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have seen a few other posts that are similar to this so I apologise in advance if this has already been asked.  However I can't get any of the solutions to work for me.

I am obtaining a chunk of JSON from a web service which I would then like to stash in Amazon's DynamoDB.  However the JSON coming back has some null and empty values in it, which DynamoDB doesn't like.

So I would to remove these values from the JSON.  I am currently using Jackson for JSON deserialising, via the readTree() method, as follows:

```
String sitesDataJson = webService.getData();

// create the object mapper and instruct it to skip null values
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper = mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

JsonNode jsonObj = null;
try {
    jsonObj = mapper.readTree(sitesDataJson);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The JSON I'm trying to read is as follows:

```
{  
   "domain_override":"",
   "id":"106949",
   "category_override":null,
   "content_topic":null,
   "modified_date":"2013-12-04 20:31:50",
   "market":{  
      "brand_labels":{  
      "op":"allow_all"
  },
  "domains":null,
  "blocked_contentattributes":{  
     "6":true
  },
  "blocked_creativetypes":{  
     "11":true,
     "10":true,
     "5":true
  },
  "brands":{  
     "ids":{  
        "5953":true,
        "4644":true,
        "8418":true,
        "25480":true,
        "95":true,
        "5650":true
     },
     "op":"block"
      },
      "blocked_languages":{  

      },
      "allow_unbranded_buyers":"0"
   },
   "type":"site",
   "status":"Active",
   "account_id":"100766",
   "deleted":"0",
   "v":"2",
   "delivery_medium":"WEB",
   "delivery_medium_id":"2",
   "content_type_id":null,
   "notes":null,
   "platform_id":null,
   "autorefresh_settings":{  

   },
   "created_date":"2013-10-16 16:49:48",
   "external_id":null,
}
```

Performing the readTree() with the NON_EMPTY or NON_NULL setting appears to make no difference.  Doing a print of jsonObj using .toString() shows the empty and null values still there.

So am I going about this in the wrong way?  Is there a better (or just correct!) way to do this?

I should also add that I have tried to do the same but using GSON, which I read removes these attributes by default.  However that is not removing them either.  So does this point to some oddity in the JSON being used?

But then I can't see how it can be as I've tried testing my code (both Jackson and GSON) with a very simple bit of JSON:

```
    String json = "{"
            + "\"name\" : \"val1\","
            + "\"address\" : null"
            + "}";
```

But this still does not remove the address attribute when readTree() is used.  Does this imply that the NON_NULL and NON_EMPTY settings have no effect on the readTree() method?  Are they only in fact for when objects are serialised to JSON?  Do I really need to read my JSON in to a POJO to be able to handle null or empty values?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the version of Jackson library you are using?

Comment: I am using version 2.5.1 of Jackson.

Comment: It seems to me that `null` values are fine, but empty strings (or arrays) are not. The solution given by @AnindaBhattacharyya worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure 100% if the solution I am proposing will work for your case, but there is a way to use custom deserializers during the deserialization process.

```
StringDeserializer deserializer = new StringDeserializer();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("StringDeserializerModule",
                      new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
module.addDeserializer(String.class, deserializer);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Now you can add more custom desirializers for the properties you think null/ empty can be present and customize the deserialize() representation.

```
class StringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String>
{
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
   {
        //Customize
   }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work with jackson 2.10.2